# HTML "value" field not pre-populating form when using Angular

Tags: html, angular, forms

I'm trying to get a form with the field Exchange already populated as "HELLO". Using `value` in HTML is not working and the field is showing up blank.

I tried adding `autocomplete=off`, but that did not work either.

```
<div class="form-group">

    <label for="AccountRef">Account Ref</label>
        <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="accountref" name="accountref" [(ngModel)]="newAccount.accountRef">
                <div class="input-group-append"></div>
              </div>

    <label for="Client">Client Name</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="client" name="client" [(ngModel)]="newAccount.client">
            <div class="input-group-append"></div>
        </div>

    <label for="Exchange">Exchange</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="exchange" name="exchange" value ="HELLO" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="newAccount.exchange">
            <div class="input-group-append"></div>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: As far as I see, you have additional 'space' after 'value'.
Have you tried different browsers?
What webkit are you testing on? (M.)

Comment: I just tried it with plain HTML (deleted the angular `[(ngModel)]=...`) and it worked fine. So it's likely something to do with that, if that narrows down your problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using two way binding `[(ngModel)]=newAccount.exchange` 
you need to populate value using newAccout.exchange

So in your ts/js file give default value Try this:`newAccout.exchange="Hello"`

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me. Try another browser or better another IDE -Sublime, Webstorm, Visual Code etc.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ashok said you need to populate '*newAccount.exchange*' but if you want to just populate the value html without [(ngModel)] you need **1 way data binding**.

`<input type="text" id="exchange" name="exchange" [value]="newAccount.exchange" autocomplete="off">`